# How do I add a container user to a user group in the Docker host?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm currently experimenting on Docker specifically on the aspect where a user inside given container affects the Docker host itself. Ultimately, I want the user to be able to run containers on its very own host from inside its container. It kind of sounds a little absurd, but I'm hoping it works.

At the moment, I'm looking for a way for that given user to be part of the Docker host's `docker` group. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

From the perspective of the Docker host, any users inside the container are treated exactly the same as a user outside the container with the same UID (not the same name!), regardless of whether the UID is actually in use on the host.  Unfortunately, it appears that only users with a username can belong to groups, so you can't just add the UID to the group.  Instead, you need to add the host user with the same UID to the group (or create a user with that UID if one doesn't exist).

Comment: So is it possible to change the UID of the user inside the container so that I can map it to a user on the Docker host?

Comment: Depending on your setup, you can set the UID with the `--user` option to `docker run` — or is your container not that simple?

Comment: I think the base image I'm using somehow switches from root to another non-root user. How does `--user` affect that?

Comment: `--user` causes the container's primary command to be run as the given user, just as if a `USER` directive were added to the end of the image's Dockerfile.

Comment: By "primary command" do you mean that one defined in `CMD`? I think the base image does some root level stuff, then switches to the other user before doing what it's ultimately supposed to do...

Comment: Yes, unless you specify another command to `docker run`, in which case that becomes the primary command.  Does the base image do its stuff as part of the process of building the image or only when it's run?

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm not really sure how to answer it. However, to make things simple: let's say I build an image based on ubuntu, under which I create a new user named `psycho`. If I'm logged in to the Docker host as `punch`, how do I run `/bin/bash` as `psycho` mapped to `punch`?

Comment: `docker run --user punch ubuntu /bin/bash`

Comment: It doesn't work because that causes Docker to look for user `punch` in the container, and there is only `psycho` in there (aside from `root`).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script to generate dockerfiles on the fly with the current user added on the container and the docker group. Here is the meat of it:

```sh
# get the current user's info
user=$USER
uid=`id -u $user`
gid=`id -g $user`

# get gid for group docker
RESULT=$(id -g docker 2>&1)
if [ 1 -ne $? ] ; then
    docker_gid=$RESULT
fi

echo FROM ubuntu:14.04

echo MAINTAINER Nobody "no-reply@nothere.com"

echo USER root
echo "RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install docker-engine"
echo "RUN /bin/bash -c 'getent passwd ${user} || \
    adduser --system --gid ${gid} ${docker_group} --uid ${uid} --shell /bin/bash ${user} || \
    usermod -l ${user} \$(getent passwd ${uid} | cut -d: -f1)'"

if [ -n "$docker_gid" ] ; then
    echo "RUN /bin/bash -c 'getent group docker && groupmod --gid ${docker_gid} docker \
        || groupadd --gid ${docker_gid} docker'"
    echo "RUN /bin/bash -c 'groups ${user} | grep docker || usermod --groups ${docker_gid} ${user}'"
fi
```

HTH!

Comment: Also if you want to share the docker daemon from the host: `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

Comment: This does not answer the question asked about adding a container-internal user to a host group.