# How to find "Docker Host URI" to be used in Jenkins "Docker Plugin"?

Tags: docker, jenkins-docker

Is there any command which we can run and find out the "Docker Host URI"? I found some of related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178824/how-to-find-docker-rest-api-url) but didn't get it exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is the docker host uri

tcp://127.0.0.1:2375

But before that you need to add this 
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

In `/etc/default/docker` at the end of file, then restart the docker.onec restarted docker.sock will run in 2375 and add this tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 in Jenkins

Comment: Additionally to change DOCKER_OPTS you probably should check what is your docker host IP address is, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container Then you should put this IP along with the port specified in DOCKER_OPTS into 'Manage Jenkins/Configure System/Docker Host URI'. Suppose IP is 172.17.0.1 and port is 2375, then Docker Host URI would be: `tcp://172.17.0.1:2375`

Comment: how to do this in docker for windowsCE ?

Comment: If you enter this in your Jenkins agent config, you'll be creating agent containers inside your Jenkins host.  If you run docker on the Jenkins host and this is what you want to do, then you can use the loopback address (127.0.0.1).  Otherwise, for example if you run Jenkins in a container and you want the agents to be in separate containers, you need another answer.  See the answer from @shaik47.

Answer (score 29):

Jenkins Docker Plugin Configuration when running jenkins as container

1. First Install Docker Plugin.
2. Go to Manage Jenkins -> System Configuration -> Scroll down to botton -> Add Cloud -> Docker.
3. If you are running jenkins as container, in the docker host uri field you have to enter unix or  tcp address of the docker host. But since you are running jenkins as container, the container can't reach docker host unix port.
4. So, we have to run another container that can mediate between docker host and jenkins container. It will public docker host's unix port as its tcp port. Follow the instructions to create socat container https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/
5. After creating the socat container, you can go back the docker configuration in jenkins and enter tcp://socat-container-ip:2375
6. Test Connection should succeed now.

Comment: This is the correct answer for people using **Docker for MacOS** and running  **Jenkins in a container**. After days of research, @shaik47 answer was what worked for me.
MacOS Mojave: 10.14.5, Docker for MacOS: 2.1, Engine: 19.03

Comment: Thanks @shaik47 it works for me. My configuration is MacOS Mojava: 10.14.6 Docker Engine 19.03.5

Comment: Above solution works well for AWS Cent OS as well where Jenkins container tries to configure Docker hub. Used below two commands to find ip address of socat container. Thank you very much.....
docker ps
docker inspect container_name | grep IPAddress

Comment: @Shaik47 : do i need to provide any connection between socat and Jenkins as i followed  step#4 and #5 but still failing with CONNECTION REFUSED error.Please help if you have pointers...

Answer (score 15):

The other option would be to enter Docker Host URI "unix: ///var/run/docker.sock", it worked for me, I hope that it is also.

Comment: It works perfectly without any other change on the system. Thanks!

Comment: I had to remove a space between `unix:` and `///var`. Other than that, it works!

Comment: On Mac - jenkins - Error: java.io.IOException: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

If your docker running at the same host were you use Jenkins inside a container than you can use **unix:///var/run/docker.sock** as the “Docker Host URI”, but you must check & obtain the permissions for jenkins user by using:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the OS X, the HOST URL is:

```
unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

*to extend the discussion about **Permissions** from the [Answer Post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090728/9549068)*

#### situation

*following is what I am trying to do & worked 

-- I am not sure that what Im doing is proper or not 

-- regarding the design of `Docker_Plugin & dynamically spawn cloud Jenkins_Agent & unix:///var/run/docker.sock & Docker-in-docker problem (dind)` 

if what i did below is proper, keep reading*

- you have a ec2 instance `EE` with Docker `DD` installed
- you have a Jenkins_Controller running inside an Docker_Container `FF` -- spawned by `DD`

- you want to dynamically spawn cloud nodes -- Docker_Container with Jenkins_Agent inside, so you used the Docker_Plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/
- you want to use the Docker `DD` as the Docker who spawns the Docker_Container with Jenkins_Agent (the Docker_Host) \

  - (- you dont want a remote Docker_Host) \
  - -- so your Docker_Container with Jenkins_Agent will be spawned as Sibling Docker_Container to `FF` (instead of Docker-in-docker) \

- so you mounted the volume by `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

  - eg: you started `FF` with following

    ```
    docker run \
      --name jenkins_main \
      -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
      -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
      --restart=on-failure \
      --detach \
      jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17
    ```
- so you configured `Cloud jenkinsDockerAgent Configuration` > `Docker Host URI` > `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

- you `Test Connection` > get `Permission Deny`

#### solution

- in ec2 instance `EE` run the following command 
  `sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user` (or `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`)
- in `EE`, restart Docker `DD` (& the Jenkins inside) 
  `systemctl restart docker`

#### explain

*(I can be wrong)*

- group `docker` has permission to the `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`
- `ec2-user` is the default user for ec2 instance (depends on your ami though)

- `sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user`
  adds the `ec2-user` to the group `docker`

- user `ec2-user` in `EE` has uid `1000`
- inside Docker_Container `FF` there is an user called `jenkins` 
  -- which is the actual user that runs the Jenkins & require the Permission \
- user `jenkins` in `FF` has the same uid `1000` as `ec2-user` 
  -- which links the permission from inside the container `FF` to the outside `EE`

#### note

- you may use `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` 
  `$USER` returns the current user -- which is normally `ec2-user`

  - if you use `$USER` when you are `root` user -- then you make a mistake
- you may instead go inside `FF` 
  & change the permission of the `/var/run/docker.sock` -- so everyone can read & write to it::

  ```
  docker exec -it --user root jenkins_main /bin/bash
  chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
  ```

  - but when the container restart, this seems need to be set again
- <strike>here is the full `userdata` (bash script for ec2 start up) //TODO</strike>

- *(there may be other notes / reference I missed to write)*
- *seems many other people in other posts are talking about: 

  Jenkins_Controller in `EE` ec2 directly; not inside `FF` which is a Docker_Container (or whatever other cases); 

  so the fix actually seems not that trivial*

#### reference

> sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins

- [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)

> chmod 664 /var/run/docker.sock

- [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)

> From the perspective of the Docker host, any users inside the container are treated exactly the same as a user outside the container with the same UID (not the same name!), regardless of whether the UID is actually in use on the host. Unfortunately, it appears that only users with a username can belong to groups, so you can't just add the UID to the group. Instead, you need to add the host user with the same UID to the group (or create a user with that UID if one doesn't exist).

- [How do I add a container user to a user group in the Docker host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659707/how-do-i-add-a-container-user-to-a-user-group-in-the-docker-host)

> In the container, Jenkins [user ID](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/d9183c0777d179e7e7435b90ae892bc87bdac552/11/debian/buster/hotspot/Dockerfile#L7) and [group ID](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/d9183c0777d179e7e7435b90ae892bc87bdac552/11/debian/buster/hotspot/Dockerfile#L8) are set to 1000. The user ID as well as Docker group ID in the container, need to match on the host. This will allow Jenkins (with UID 1000) to create containers similar to how it happens on the host.

- https://www.nixknight.com/2021/04/jenkins-docker-in-docker/

> If your container doesn’t have the group `docker`, you can create it by typing this command:

- https://medium.com/igorgsousa-tech/docker-in-docker-with-jenkins-permission-problem-637f45549947