# Containerized Jenkins: establish connection to docker cloud in internal network

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-for-mac

I am trying to connect a mac to a raspberry running Jenkins, to start docker build slaves on the mac on demand. But I can't establish the connection in Jenkins' docker cloud configuration.

My setup is as follows:

- raspberry pi at 192.168.2.111: Jenkins running in docker
- mac mini at 192.168.2.220 using docker for mac: this should run docker containers as build slaves on demand via Jenkins docker plugin

The SSH connection from Jenkins to mac works. The mac agent is up and running.

Now I want to use the docker plugin for Jenkins and trying to configure the docker cloud.

As docker for mac does not run directly on the host machine (but on hyperkit), [they say](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/770#issuecomment-252560286) I should run `socat` to expose the Unix socket like this:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 127.0.0.1:2376:2375 alpine/socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
```

The container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
76a75c5249d7        alpine/socat        "socat tcp-listen:23…"   19 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       127.0.0.1:2376->2375/tcp   compassionate_feynman
```

Then on the Raspberry pi where the Jenkins container is running, I have also added

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

at the end of the file `/etc/default/docker` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47713940/2366975).

Then in Jenkins cloud config "docker", I set "Docker Host URI" to `tcp://127.0.0.1:2376`, and the Docker Hostname (The mac mini) to `192.168.2.220`. Testing this setting failed.

[image]

All the tutorials I find seem to have Jenkins on the same host where the docker slaves will be run. I assume this is why the socat container is not enough in my case?

What is also interesting: 
Running `curl 127.0.0.1:2376/version`on the mac works (shows expected information), but running `curl 192.168.2.220:2376/version` from the raspberry does not work (Connection refused). Maybe this can help someone who knows more about networks...

Answer (score 1):

Captain Obvious strikes back.

Just use the network IP instead of localhost when starting socat on the mac.

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 192.168.2.220:2376:2375 alpine/socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
```